# Active model OTP not generating new secret key after 30 seconds sleep

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twilio

I am trying implement `active_model_otp` on a sample rails application. 
My user model has `name` and `email` columns. After following the necessary steps from the documentation I first created a user as follows on rails console:

`User.create(name: "Abc", email: "example@email.com")`

This created a record as follows:

```
<User id: 1, name: "Abc", email: "example@email.com", created_at: "2017-04-28 07:12:25", updated_at: "2017-04-28 07:12:25", otp_secret_key: "lol6rrtqppy46xfs">
```

Then I assigned:

`user = User.last` and

`user.otp_secret_key` gave the otp that was generated which is

```
=>"lol6rrtqppy46xfs"
```

Then I ran

`sleep(2)`

According to given documentation it supposed to generate a new otp after 2 seconds. But when I gave: `user.otp_secret_key` again in the console after 2 seconds it is returning the same old otp.

`=>"lol6rrtqppy46xfs"`

What am I missing ?

Comment: Did you tried to reload the resource (the user) before querying for the otp for the second time ? You can do it with `user.reload`

Comment: Tried `user.reload`. Still the same `otp`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

The `otp_secret_key` is the string that is used to generate the actual OTP code that you send to the user. It is the secret that is shared to the user (via the QR code) and so it needs to match on both the user's auth app as well as your server.

The generated OTP should change every 30 seconds. As far as I can see it uses the default interval of the [ROTP gem](https://github.com/mdp/rotp), [which is 30 seconds](https://github.com/mdp/rotp/blob/master/lib/rotp/totp.rb#L2).

The method to get the OTP is `otp_code`. So to check it's working, try:

```
user = User.last
puts user.otp_code
sleep(30)
puts user.otp_code
```

Let me know if that helps at all.

Comment: Of-course its `otp_code`. Damn! I been passing `otp_secret_key` all this time looking at the activerecord column. Thanx for pointing me that. How often does one's question get answered by THE @philnash